# Side effects / observables in angular pipes

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

got a question for you !
Is using pipe with side effect(s) acceptable ?

Indeed i'm loading an item collection with a childId property in each, 
and want to display child informations in the parent list.

Because this child entity is used everywhere in my app, i don't want to care about loading it each time i need it, so i did something like this :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'childInfo$'
})
export class FullModelNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  transform(childId: string, ...args: any[]): Observable<string> {
    if (!childId) {
      return of('');
    }
    return this.myService.loadIfNeeded(childId);
  }
}
```

and then use it like

```
item.childId | childInfo$ | async
```

i'm not totally sure about this practice, could anyone please tell me if i'm doing right ?
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: i think the answer to your question primarily depends on implementation of `this.myService.loadIfNeeded` if it encompases some sort of caching mechanism i guess you ll be just fine :) but i also would like to hear other ideas.

Comment: in fact in use ngrx, and 
1. dispatch a action which triggers an effect to send an httprequest if needed value is not already in store
2. returns an hot observable which selects my data in the ngrx store, with a share() at the end, as pipe transform trigger is a little tricky.